# how to use wait function in android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, delay, wait

In first run ,after opening the application it should wait for 1 second and open navigation drawer, after 1 second navigation drawer should close

```
SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!preferences.getBoolean("Man",false))
    {

    // wait 1 second            

     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

   // wait 1 second

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Man",true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: use Handler with postDelayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Handler` to achieve wait time in your code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Actions to do after 1 second
                }
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` with recursion

```
boolean firstOpen = false;
public void animateDrawer(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                         if(!firstOpen)
                           {
                             // open your Drawer here
                             firstOpen = true;
                             animateDrawer();
                           }
                           else
                           {
                             // close your Drawer here
                           }
                        }
                    },1000);
//1000 is a 1 second delay
}
```

Comment: How can i close it, after 1 sec

Comment: It is working on a boolean condition on first 1 sec it will call itself, and after 2 sec it will not call itself so after closing the drawer it will end itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `CountDown Timer`,

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

Or Post Delayed,

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        Toast.makeText(c, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
      }
    }, 1500);
```